# fstream .txt and putting it into a char array to compare with another string

Tags: c++

First of all Im new to c++, currently have a data file which is .txt,first string is the answer to the questions, example ABBCACBB, second string started with student ID space and the answer.

example of .txt

```
'         TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT'
'ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT'
'ABC54302 TTTFFFTT TFTFTFFTTFT'
```

I have trouble fitting them into a char[] and comparing.
anyone can guide me which kind of method i can use to compare them and output should be similar like this:

example of output \n

```
'         TFFTFFTTTTFFTFTFTFTT'
'ABC54301 TFTFTFTT TFTFTFFTTFT   14/20 80% A+'
'ABC54302 TTTFFFTT TFTFTFFTTFT   13/20 75% B+'
```

Thank you and sorry for the trouble.

btw my data.txt got about 150 entries.

Comment: Don't attempt to "fitting them into a char[]", use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead. Using that and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) it becomes very easy to read the file.

Comment: but i do need to compare them letter by letter from char[10] to char[x] to get the final result?

Comment: That's still possible.

Comment: i know how get line works, while (getline(data,output,'/n') then how do i take the 10th character to compare with the 10th character of the second line?

Comment: `std::string` has a `[]` operator, that can be used just like for an array. So read the first line separately and save it. Then use e.g. `current_line[10] == first_line[10]`.